# layout does not see library

Tags: java, android

[PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) imported into Layout and writing

```
<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
android: id = "@ + id / pull_to_refresh_listview"
android: layout_height = "fill_parent"
android: layout_width = "fill_parent" />
```

But why that flies the project. Hovering on this component writes

```
Can not find declaration to go to
```

Tell me how to fix this error, can anyone come across?

UPD: LOGS

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.isakovch.aukg/com.isakovch.aukg.BottomItems.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
```

Comment: share your logcat log

Comment: How have you imported the library?

Comment: File -> New -> Import Module

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 4
        targetSdkVersion 4
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Try syncing the gradle and doing a clean and rebuild of the project.

EDIT:

You need to add

`compile project(':mobihelp_sdk_android_v1.5.4')` to your gradle, but obviously replace `:mobihelp_sdk_android_v1.5.4` with the name of the module you imported, then sync the gradle and it should work

Comment: both through the Gradle set. They do not have any link

Answer (score 0):

Add into gradle dependencies and sync:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:0.9.9'
}
```

Comment: Does not see. All the same